# How to change a background image?

Tags: java, android

I studied all possible answers and found something that should work:

```
int[] tabelazdjec={R.drawable.pic2,R.drawable.pic3};
LinearLayout mylay=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mylay);
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.yess);
    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run()
        {
            for(int i=0;i<tabelazdjec.length;i++)
            {
            try
            {

                mylay.setBackgroundResource(tabelazdjec[i]);
                sleep(500);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }}
    };
    timer.start();
```

It doesn't. The error appears in the second line where I declare the LinearLayout variable. If I move the declaration into try{}catch{} part, the app runs but try{} doesn't execute, so it is quite certainly this exact line.
The xml file goes as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/mylay"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/pic1" >


</LinearLayout>
```

Sorry if the question seems trivial, i've spent last few hours staring at that line and can't find anything wrong with it. Maybe I'm blind...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't initialize a `View` until you have inflated its `layout`. Move the `LinearLayout` initialization to below `setContentView()`

```
LinearLayout mylay;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.yess);
    mylay=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mylay);
    Thread timer = new Thread(){
```

Your `Views` will return `null` if you try to initialize them before inflating the `layout` that they belong to as with `setContentView()`.

Also, as E.Odebugg has pointed out in a comment, you are trying to update a `UI` element in a background `Thread` which will be your next problem. You need to use `runOnUiThread()` to update the `UI`.

Comment: also he/she is trying to change a UI component from a background Thread.